# How can a website that is downloaded with wget be used?

Tags: wget

I downloaded an entire website with `wget` but don't know how to actually use this website now, how is this done?

Comment: Used how? To achieve what? The download will be a snapshot of the site as it was at that moment, any dynamic content will be lost.

Comment: What language is the site in? What framework is used? Do you have a local server installed? Need lots more info.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mirrored the site, you should be able to navigate to the directory/folder you saved it in using your system's file manager and then open the top level file (usually index.html) in a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ wget --help | less 
...
Recursive download:
  -r,  --recursive                 specify recursive download
  -l,  --level=NUMBER              maximum recursion depth (inf or 0 for infinite)
       --delete-after              delete files locally after downloading them
  -k,  --convert-links             make links in downloaded HTML or CSS point to
                                     local files
       --convert-file-only         convert the file part of the URLs only (usually known as the basename)
       --backups=N                 before writing file X, rotate up to N backup files
...
```

Note the `-k, --convert-links` keywords.

If you wish to browse the local copies -- without ending up in the original website -- either `-k` or `--convert-links` is a must as you use wget to download the copy.